# Synchronizing slicers automatically

Tags: vba, excel, slicers

I'm new here, so please don't get mad if I'm asking something I shouldn't.

I was trying to contact Rene from the accepted answer of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36157201/6527619) but I can't seam to find a way to contact members...

I'm trying to use the code that he posted, but I'm getting an "User-defined type not defined" error on the line "Private mCacheManager As New clsCacheManager" of step 4.

I put steps 1, 2 and 3 into separate class modules and step 4 into the "ThisWorkbook" code. Am i doing this wrong?

can anyone help? I'm using office 2016.

Thanks

Comment: Can I get mad if you didn't do something you should have done? Like providing your code in question?

Comment: @DavidG, I'm sorry. I'm using the code Rene posted in his answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26810376/synchronizing-slicers/36157201#36157201

Comment: I've in no way taken time to understand the code, but should `Private mCacheManager As New clsCacheManager` not be replaced by `Dim mCacheManager As clsCacheManager : Set mCacheManager = New clsCacheManager` as in [this Chip Pearson article](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/classes.aspx)?

Comment: Ricardo: Do you want to filter on just one item at a time? Or do you want to filter on multiple items? If just one item at a time, the code posted at https://stackoverflow.com/a/26812494/2507160 will be much faster. If multiple items, then if your slicers have lots of items in them, the code you link to will possibly be very slow. Here's two links that discuss the  problems with execution speed:
http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2013/11/14/filtering-pivots-based-on-external-ranges/
http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2015/11/17/filtering-pivottables-with-vba-deselect-slicers-first/